# React JS - ESLint - Rules for ignoring components with UNSAFE_componentWillMount, UNSAFE_componentWillUpdate, and UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend, eslint

Currently, I'm getting these linting errors:

`ESLint: UNSAFE_componentWillUpdate should be placed after someFunction (react/sort-comp)`

and

`ESLint: Identifier 'UNSAFE_componentWillUpdate' is not in camel case. (camelcase)`

Currently, I'm not able to find the correct rules to add to `.eslintrc` to apply to the prepended `UNSAFE_` component lifecycles. I'm trying to make it apply to both `react/sort-comp` and `camelcase` rules, any clues/help would be appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add this to your eslint

```
"camelcase": [
  "error", {
    "ignoreDestructuring": true,
    "allow": [ "^UNSAFE_" ]
  }
],
```

This basically just allows all the renamed `UNSAFE_` lifecycle methods.

Comment: Where is the eslint config file ? Edit:In the project root folder: /.eslintrc  The code needs to be added under the rules: part